# Draw to UIView subview using an instance of that subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, drawing, core-graphics

I am trying to draw to a UIView subview from another class.

1. `MainViewController` with a view that I have dragged a UIView into in IB.
2. I have created a `DrawView` class and changed the UIView's(the one I dragged onto the `MainController`'s view in IB earlier) class to `DrawView`.
3. I can draw to that `DrawView` UIView subview by coding in `DrawView` so that works as expected.
4. I have a custom `UITableViewController` class and would like to draw in the "`DrawView` UIView" from the custom `UITableViewController`. How to do so?

   - I have tried creating a new instance of `DrawView` from the custom `UITableViewController` and creating functions in `DrawView` that I can call to draw. Doesn't work because my created instance of `DrawView` is a different instance than the "`DrawView` UIView" in IB that is created on launch. The newly created `DrawView`'s bounds are zero, too, passing in bounds for `initWithFrame` doesn't work.

I don't understand how I can get the same instance of `DrawView` created in IB to use in the custom `UITableViewController`.

In case the above is too wordy, I want to call drawing methods to draw in a UIView subview in its class from another class.

How can I implement this? Thanks.

Comment: You would have to make your UITableViewController the "drawing" delegate of your DrawView. I dont think this is how you want to do it though.  I think you should have your controller pass messages by means of function calls etc... to your view that knows how to draw the data the controller sends to it.

Comment: @trumpetlicks <br>Yes, that was what I had in mind at the beginning. How can the UITableViewController call a function in the DrawView controller when the DrawView is connected to the UIView in IB? I'm not sure how to reference to the "IB connected" DrawView.  
The main reason for creating a DrawView was so that I could call something like '[drawView drawCircle]' from another class and all the drawing code would be contained within the DrawView file.

Comment: In your controller code (header) you simply have to instead of having an instantiation with your drawview type, it will be IBOutlet drawviewtype * mydrawview;  When you place IBOutlet in front of the instantiation you are telling the toolchain that this is an instantiation you want to be able to see in interface builder.  This essentially allows you to access the connectability from IB, and the code calling of your drawview implementation from your controller code.

Comment: @trumpetlicks I haven't had time to try that yet, but is there a way to change the subview UIView class at runtime and not need to set things up in IB?  
<br/>  
To phrase another way: Connect 'DrawView' (a subview UIView) to another class, lets say a custom 'NSObject' class without IB? I would like to let a custom 'NSObject' class call functions in 'DrawView' so that 'DrawView''s functions would draw to its subview UIView.

Comment: So if I understand your question, then I think the answer is NO.  You cant instantiate an object of one type, then try and turn it into another type at runtime.  What I have done in the past, is have multiple different UIView types, and simply made only the one I want shown visible, making all others (even though they may be one right on top another) invisible, and touch inactive.

Comment: I tried connecting 'DrawView' to the 'MainViewController' in IB and that works all very well.  However, when I apply the same steps to give another class, say NSObject 'PeachClass' the 'DrawView' instance, 'PeachClass' does not appear to get access to the DrawView' class at all even though I have it imported and an IBOutlet in 'PeachClass.h'. Screenshot of IB setup [here](http://i.imgur.com/gKqpdwS.png).